# Error connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine deployed Node.js app

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

I have a Node.js backend application using Express and **Sequelize**, deployed on Google App Engine, and connected to a Google Cloud SQL database (MySQL). The application **works fine locally** when I test the API to add data in Cloud SQL Database, but after deploying to App Engine, I'm getting a SequelizeConnectionError with the message 'connect ETIMEDOUT'. This happens when I try to test CRUD operations against the Cloud SQL database from the deployed app.

[Error logs screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ3rZ.png)

[Postman error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajNsq.png)

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this connection error when connecting to a Cloud SQL database from a Node.js app deployed on Google App Engine?

--- More ---

- The database connection configuration in *dbconfig.js* is correct and works locally.
- The error suggests a timeout issue, but I'm not sure what might be causing it in the deployed environment.
- I've tried deploying with different Node.js runtime versions on App Engine but still encounter the same error.
- All of the connection errors happen only when I test the API with the hosted url

Below is the code related to the database connection:
[dbconfig.js]
[dbconfig.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBfIJ.png)

[models/index.js]
[models/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp6E5.png)

[app.yaml]

```
runtime: nodejs18  # Node Version
entrypoint: node app.js
```

[Authorized Networks in Cloud SQL]
[Cloud SQL Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsMBK.png)

[IAM]
[Cloud Permissions in IAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTTsw.png)

Comment: Please post your configuration here -- the screenshot doesn't clarify what `DB_SOCKET` is actually defined as.